# How to define circular referenced JSON definition by using spray-json?

Tags: scala, spray-json

I want to define circular referenced structure JSON with spray-json, so I try to define like below.

```
final case class A(b: B)
final case class B(a: A)

trait AProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val aProtocol: RootJsonFormat[A] = rootFormat(lazyFormat(jsonFormat1(A)))
}
```

But I got an error which is

```
<console>:18: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type MyProtocol.this.JF[B]
   implicit val aProtocol: RootJsonFormat[A] = rootFormat(lazyFormat(jsonFormat1(A)))
```

Please give me some advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have jsonFormat for A but what with B. You are using lazyFormat well but completely forgot about other dependency. Try this:

```
final case class A(b: B)
final case class B(a: A)

trait AProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val aProtocol: RootJsonFormat[A] = rootFormat(lazyFormat(jsonFormat1(A)))
  implicit val bProtocol: RootJsonFormat[B] = rootFormat(lazyFormat(jsonFormat1(B)))
}
```

Comment: I tried like you said and it works fine. Thanks for your advise.